# why LinearLayouts return null object reference after configuration changes?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

i am setting `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest for activity to not be destroyed and re-created  .
but if i tried to use any of LinearLayout objects after screen rotates"first rotation does not return error second one return error [full details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048409/null-object-reference-if-configuration-changes)" it return null !

**Question** does `LinearLayout` objects return null after configuration changes if (activity declared in manifest like that)  ?
thanx in advance!

Comment: Hey I am able to Get the Id of Linear Layout in Configuration changed Method in Activity. So May i show your code ?

Comment: code in full details link above

Comment: I have added one simple example on above link please check it out.